# While r-markdown creating HTML report ,CSS stylesheet not working in Docker based on Ubuntu

Tags: html, css, docker, ubuntu, r-markdown

I'm trying to use Docker image to create rmarkdown HTML report. When I'm using the same command on Ubuntu server with the same input files (.Rmd, .R, .css) everything is ok, but when I try to use Docker based on Ubuntu 20.04 (*rocker/r-ubuntu:20.04*) then my report is not the same.

My report in Docker is 1-2MB smaller and some fonts and styles are not included compared to server report.

Is it possible that Docker can't use urls for css stylesheets or maybe the reason is lack of some package?

Comment: After small change from 20.04 (focal) to 18.04 (bionic) the Docker report changed it's size about 1MB up and there is small difference in style. Docker report is still worse than server report.